# How to use a for loop to count the number of zeros in each column on a worksheet in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I am trying to make a sub that loops through 31 columns on one worksheet to find the number of 0's that exist in each column. Each column can have a different amount of data, up to 25,000 cells in each column. I need to take the number of 0's counted and paste it in the 47th row of each column. The data that I need to count starts in row 49 and can go to 25,049. My thought process was to count the number of rows with data instead of having VBA look through possible blank cells to save performance. When I ran the code below, it never counted more than 1 zero in each row. Most of them said there was no instances of a zero when there would be like 9 of them. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
Sub FindingZeros()
'________________________________________
'TO DO:
'Filter data in this workbook for 0's and
'count instances
'________________________________________

Dim zeros As Integer
Dim currcol As Integer
Dim temp As Worksheet
Set temp = Worksheets("306 Toyota 2.5L")

For currcol = 2 To 32
    Dim lastrow1 As Long
    lastrow1 = temp.Range(Cells(49, currcol), Cells(temp.Rows.Count, currcol)).End(xlUp).Row
    zeros = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(49, currcol), Cells(lastrow1, currcol)), 0)
    
    temp.Cells(47, currcol).Value = zeros
Next currcol

End Sub
```

Comment: Is your lastrow returning the proper last row? Try `lastrow1 = temp.Cells(Rows.Count, currcol).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Why not just use COUNTIF on the entire column and skip finding the last row?

Comment: In my code lastrow1 ended up return 10 instead of like 6,700 something. When I changed it to your line it ended up working! Thank you so much.

Comment: I can't used CountIf on the entire thing because rows 1 through 46 have a bunch of formulas that can contain a 0 that are used to generate histograms according to each columns data that shouldn't be included in the zero count that I need for the raw data below row 48. so I couldn't countif the entire column.

Comment: You can still skip finding the last row and just use `Rows.Count`... count all the way to the bottom of the sheet, starting from row 49.

Comment: `temp.Cells(47, currcol).Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(49, currcol), Cells(Rows.Count, currcol)), 0)` Also easily achievable with a formula.

Comment: Oh I see what you were saying. Sorry, I wasn't thinking. That also worked when I just tested it. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue you were having was identifying the last used row of a column, in this instance we do not need to know the range but just the last row, so lastrow1 only needs the last row number.

Then we do not need to set a variable of for the zeros as the value can be put directly in to the cell.

Refer to the comments:

```
Sub FindingZeros()

Dim currcol As Integer
Dim temp As Worksheet
Dim lastrow1 As Long

Set temp = Worksheets("306 Toyota 2.5L")
 
For currcol = 2 To 32

    ' find last used row of column 
    lastrow1 = Cells(temp.Rows.Count, currcol).End(xlUp).Row 

    ' set the value of the cell to the counted zeroes. 
    Cells(47, currcol).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(49, currcol), Cells(lastrow1, currcol)), 0)
    
Next currcol    

End Sub
```